# C# Group by one property select the newest one from the group

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a list of objects that have a following structure

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid OrderId { get;set;}
    public DateTime OrderDate {get;set;}
    public Guid CustomerId { get;set;}
}
```

From the list I have to chose for each customer newest order. I know I need to use group by CustomerId, but how do I select only newest order from the group?
Thanks

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: orders.GroupBy(x => x.CustomerId) that gives me a set, now I need to order the orders inside the groups by the orderdate and pick only the newest one from each group. I don't know how to achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably looking for something like that

```
orders.GroupBy(o => o.CustomerId).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderDate).First());
```

So within each group you will sort by the order date and then select the first one.